# How to understand this behavior of goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main
import (  
    "fmt"
    "time"
)
type field struct {  
    name string
}
func (p *field) print() {  
    fmt.Println(p.name)
}
func main() {  
    data := []field{ {"one"},{"two"},{"three"} }
    for _,v := range data {
        go v.print()
    }
    <-time.After(1 * time.Second)
}
```

why does this code print 3 "three" instead of "one" "two" "three" in any order?

Answer (score 7):

There is a data race.

The code implicitly takes address of variable `v` when [evaluating arguments to the goroutine function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements).  Note that the call `v.print()` is [shorthand for the call `(&v).print()`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls).

The loop changes the value of variable `v`.

When goroutines execute, it so happens that `v` has the last value of the loop. That's not guaranteed. It could execute as you expected.

It's helpful and easy to run programs with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html). This data race is detected and reported by the detector.

One fix is to create another variable scoped to the inside of the loop:

```
for _, v := range data {
    v := v        // short variable declaration of new variable `v`.
    go v.print()
}
```

With this change, the address of the inner variable `v` is taken when evaluating the arguments to the goroutine.  There is a unique inner variable `v` for each iteration of the loop.

Yet another way to fix the problem is use a slice of pointers:

```
data := []*field{ {"one"},{"two"},{"three"} } // note '*'
for _, v := range data {
    go v.print()
}
```

With this change, the individual pointers in the slice are passed to the goroutine, not the address of the range variable `v`.

Another fix is to use the address of the slice element:

```
data := []field{ {"one"},{"two"},{"three"} } // note '*'
for i:= range data {
    v := &data[i]
    go v.print()
}
```

Because pointer values are typically used with types having a pointer receiver, this subtle issue does not come up often in practice.  Because `field` has a pointer receiver, it would be typical to use `[]*field` instead of `[]field` for the type of `data` in the question.

If the goroutine function is in an anonymous function, then a common approach for avoiding the issue is to pass the range variables as an argument to the anonymous function:

```
for _, v := range data {
  go func(v field) {
    v.print() // take address of argument v, not range variable v.
  }(v)
}
```

Because the code in the question does not already use an anonymous function for the goroutine, the first approach used in this answer is simpler.

Comment: To add to this: the issue could be addressed by updating the `print` method so it uses a value receiver instead of a pointer receiver (which sometimes may not be an option, but this example clearly doesn't require a pointer receiver) [ref](https://tour.golang.org/methods/8): `func (p field) print()`. Or another option (in the case that a pointer receiver is necessary) would be to wrap the go routine in a func that passes a copy (value) of v instead of sharing v with all routines: `go func(f field) { f.print() }(v)`

Comment: @Jonathan It seems to me that in any case where the receiver needs to be a pointer, the wrap-it-in-a-func approach wouldn't help? The reasons to use a pointer receiver are either (a) to save space and avoid passing a big argument -- but now you are passing the full `v` as `f` to the anonymous function, or (b) to make changes to the original object -- but now you are making changes to the copy `f`, not to `v`.

Comment: @AlexLew yes, good point. If this func was instead processing and storing some large, significantly complex computed value (one that could vary depending on random inputs and require up to several minutes to complete) and the value needs to be stored within `v`, that would make things complicated... but in that case, perhaps the better solution would be to launch a routine from within `v`’s method... still feels kind of dirty to me, though. At this point, I’d want to try rethinking the solution since I’d get the feeling my approach is incorrect - or at least not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above there’s a race condition  it’s result depends on delays on different processes and not well defined and predictable. 
For example if you add `time.Sleep(1*time.Seconds)` you likely to get a correct result. Because usually goroutine prints faster than 1second and will have correct variable `v` but it’s a very bad way.

Golang has a special race detector tool which helps to find such situations. I recommend read about it while reading `testing`. Definitely it’s worth it.

There’s another way - explicitly pass variable value at goroutine start:

```
for _, v := range data {
     go func(iv field) {
            iv.print()
      }(v)
 }
```

Here `v` will be copied to `iv` (“internal v”) on every iteration and each goroutine will use correct value.